# The Authentication Extension threw an unexpected exception or returned a value that is not valid: identity==null. (rsAuthenticationExtensionError)

Tags: c#, .net, reportingservices-2005

I'm getting an error for the following code:

```
reportExecutionService.LogonUser(businessIdentity.Name, businessIdentity.Token, null);

execInfo = reportExecutionService.LoadReport(reportPath, null);
```

Error is coming on `LoadReport` and **not** on `LogOnUser`-->

> The Authentication Extension threw an unexpected exception or returned
>   a value that is not valid: identity==null.
>   (rsAuthenticationExtensionError)

Not sure why it's erroring.